How to report a user who uses related multiple accounts to close/downvote a question?
If a user uses related multiple accounts to close/down-vote a question, how to report him?

You can change "moderator" to "user" to make this sound slightly less targeted. But I highly doubt moderators have time for this kind of behaviour... ;)

@Pedro Yes, indeed a user :)

I suggest editing your post to remove the term "moderator".  (it is still in the Header).  You just mean to refer to a general "user", right? Might also be worth pointing out that the system automatically checks for suspicious voting patterns...a sudden flurry of downvotes on old posts, for example.  Those votes can, and frequently will, be reversed by the system.

How would you know?

Flag a question they have closed using the "In need of moderator intervention" option.  Describe the situation in the flag.
Honestly, though, I doubt any moderator has multiple accounts.
